# Reflection of eye floaters in a mirror

Tags: geometric-optics, vision

> Most eye floaters are caused by age-related changes that occur as the jelly-like substance (vitreous) inside your eyes liquifies and contracts. Scattered clumps of collagen fibers form within the vitreous and can cast tiny shadows on your retina. The shadows you see are called [floaters](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/eye-floaters/symptoms-causes/syc-20372346).

If you look in a mirror while getting floaters would you see an image of the floaters in the mirror? Since they are basically shadows on the retina, I think we should theoretically be able to see an image but practically not because the shadow image would be very small.

Comment: To see floaters from the front of your eye you would need to illuminate the floaters, which are sitting in the darkness of your eye, from the front. That would be a direct image of the floaters, not the shadows you normally see. But that illumination blinds you from seeing anything else. Have you ever had an eye dilation exam? The light that the optometrist is blasting into your eye to see inside your eye prevents you from seeing anything such as the your eye's reflection in the mirror.